# In Pivot join tables and return value only from one of them if it has values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have this query (SQL fiddle at the bottom):

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @listaId as NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @listaId = @selezione
SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','')+  QUOTENAME(CONVERT(DATE,data,105)) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  FORMAT ( data, 'd', 'it-IT' ) as data FROM PIANOLAVORO WHERE (data>=@dataDa and data<=@dataA)) AS [data]

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = ';WITH CTE AS(
SELECT v.data,t.cognome,s.CVDESCR FROM pianolavoro v
INNER JOIN orari s ON s.id = v.idorario
INNER JOIN dbstartprv.dbo.ANAGRAFICO_DATI t ON t.id = v.iddip
WHERE v.IDDIP in('+@listaId+')
)
SELECT COGNOME,'+@ColumnName+' FROM CTE
PIVOT (MAX(CVDESCR) FOR [data] IN('+@ColumnName+')) p
ORDER BY cognome ASC'
EXEC(@DynamicPivotQuery)
```

that gives me a result in this form:

```
       2019-03-01   2019-03-02   ...
jack       A             B
john       B             A
```

A and B are get from this join `INNER JOIN orari s ON s.id = v.idorario` and I would like to show other data instead of A, B only if **in the same day** something exists on another table.
This is the join to be added in the above query `join giustif g on t.id=g.iddip and g.idvoce=1001`

Basically if in table pianolavoro on the 1st of march Jack has "A" but **also** he has a value on the same day in giustif table (say I get only id values = 1001), I want to display this:

```
       2019-03-01   2019-03-02   ...
jack     1001            B
john       B             A
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b5228/1)
If you run the fiddle: the user Cozzolino has 2 resting days (1-2 june) and 5 working days (3-7 june) and on 6 and 7 of june he has a record in the table giustif. Now my query give me the result as in the fiddle, but I want it to be like:

```
            2019-06-01   2019-06-02   ...  2019-06-05  2019-06-06
Cozzolino     REST          REST      ...     WORK        1001
```

How can I achieve that? Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired output data will help you clarify your question  and help to understand what you want to people who want to help you.

Comment: @StepUp I added a sql fiddle and desired output based on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have to answer my own question:

`coalesce(x.descr,s.CVDESCR) as cvdescr` instead of `s.CVDESCR`
and add

```
left join giustif g on t.id=g.iddip and v.data=g.data
left join vocibase x on x.id=g.idvoce and idvoce=1001
```

Result query is:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @listaId as NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @listaId = @selezione
SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','')+  QUOTENAME(data) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  FORMAT ( data, 'd', 'it-IT' ) as data FROM PIANOLAVORO WHERE (data>=@dataDa and data<=@dataA)) AS [data]

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = ';WITH CTE AS(
SELECT v.data,t.cognome,coalesce(x.descr,s.CVDESCR) as cvdescr FROM pianolavoro v
INNER JOIN orari s ON s.id = v.idorario
INNER JOIN dbstartprv.dbo.ANAGRAFICO_DATI t ON t.id = v.iddip
left join giustif g on t.id=g.iddip and v.data=g.data
left join vocibase x on x.id=g.idvoce and idvoce=1001
WHERE v.IDDIP in('+@listaId+')
)
SELECT COGNOME,'+@ColumnName+' FROM CTE
PIVOT (MAX(CVDESCR) FOR [data] IN('+@ColumnName+')) p
ORDER BY cognome ASC'
EXEC(@DynamicPivotQuery)
```